# Mathematica fails to solve diffusion pde(focker planck)

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I am trying to solve the focker planck equation in mathematica. But this is showing lots of errors. i don't get where the problem lies.

The equation is

```
k[x_, t_] := -4*x
s = NDSolve[{\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(u[t, x, p]\)\) + p*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\(u[t, x, p]\)\) == \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(p\)]\((\((u[t, x, p] - k[x, t])\)*
        u[t, x, p])\)\) + 1*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x\)]\(u[t, x, p]\)\), 
   u[0, x, p] == E^(-5*(x)^2 + 10*(p)^2), 
   u[t, -10, p] == u[t, 10, p] == 0, 
   u[t, x, -10] == u[t, x, 10] == 0}, 
  u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, -10, 10}, {p, -10, 10}, 
  Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]
```

My initial condition is u should be initially e^(-5*(x)^2 + 10*(p)^2) and then freely evolve as this is an initial valued problem. But there are many errors like maximum number of 100 gridpoints reached, further calculations would be suppressed and lots of others. Also it says that boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent. The actual issue is, this equation does not need a boundary condition(only zero at infinity), just specifying the initial condition will do. But to use NDSOLVE, one must assign some value at boundary. As exp(-x^2-p^2) becomes very small at the boundary in this problem,I assigned a dirichlet boundary condition(u=0) but that is not working. So. overall, what is the way out?

Comment: why is `k[x_, t_] := -4*x` defined to take in `t` but it does not use it? and did you notice the `NDSolve::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.` ? might want to fix that if possible.

Comment: K is just x here, would be changed later according to the problem, the boundary condition is also my question here. I want zero at endpoints, and gaussian in between, I am nit getting how to implement that.